# Additional properties of closure and accumulation point

Tags: general-topology

prove or disprove: $(\overline{\overline{A}}) = \overline{A}$

proof: This is true, since $\overline{A}$ is closed and $A$ is closed

I am not sure if this is right, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is closed... how did you come up with that? This equality is true for any set. If you already know that $C = \overline{C}$ iff $C$ is closed, just put $C := \overline{A}$ and you are done.